# Python: Why does some code work once

Tags: python

I'm using Python 3+ in Jupyter Lab and I'm following this [tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/mlcc/feature_sets.ipynb?utm_source=mlcc&utm_campaign=colab-external&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=featuresets-colab&hl=en#scrollTo=xdVF8siZ7Lup). Establishing a variable inside a function vs. outside a function makes it work more reliably. Why?

For example, I wanted to execute the following two, but only the first one works as expected:

```
selected_training_examples = select_and_transform_features(training_examples)
selected_validation_examples = select_and_transform_features(validation_examples)
```

This is the original function definition works as expected only the first time:

```
# bucketizing latitude:
LATITUDE_RANGES = zip(range(32, 44), range(33, 45))

def select_and_transform_features(source_df):
    selected_examples = pd.DataFrame()
    selected_examples["median_income"] = source_df["median_income"]
    for r in LATITUDE_RANGES:
        selected_examples["latitude_%d_to_%d" % r] = source_df["latitude"].apply(
            lambda l: 1.0 if l >= r[0] and l < r[1] else 0.0)
    return selected_examples
```

But if I put LATITUDE_RANGES inside the function definition it works everytime:

```
def select_and_transform_features(source_df):
    # bucketizing latitude:
    LATITUDE_RANGES = zip(range(32, 44), range(33, 45))
    selected_examples = pd.DataFrame()
    selected_examples["median_income"] = source_df["median_income"]
    for r in LATITUDE_RANGES:
        selected_examples["latitude_%d_to_%d" % r] = source_df["latitude"].apply(
            lambda l: 1.0 if l >= r[0] and l < r[1] else 0.0)
    return selected_examples
```

This was a fix I learned from @RadEdje [post here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49584365/google-tensor-flow-crash-course-issues-with-representationprogramming-exercise/49597750#49597750) I'm a newbie, so I can't comment and ask directly and I thought formulating this question might be helpful for others to learn.

Researching 'why' led me to think it could be related to the fact that I'm using jupyter labs, [this post for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32409332/python-code-works-fine-first-time-but-fails-second-time). So, with LATITUDE_RANGES left outside of the function, I tried executing the following in my jupyter notebook:

```
%reload_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

However, it didn't have the same effect as moving LATITUDE_RANGES inside the function definition. So my question here is: *why would python code work once?* I have a lot to learn - *what are the keywords which describe this situation?* 
Thanks!

Comment: [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) returns an iterator, and the iterator can only be iterated one time.

Comment: thanks Aran-Fey! "iterator" was just the keyword I was missing. For others: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336726/why-cant-i-iterate-twice-over-the-same-data